# Apollo graphql: writeQuery after mutation does not trigger re-render of flatlist

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following button in a flatlist that triggers a graphql mutation and after the mutation I do a writeQuery to update the local cache (store). In the update functionf of the mutation I am updating two fields within the cache. essentially when the user touches the like button I chang the boolean value of the like to true and update the like count for that post by +1 (similiar to twitter). However the components in the flatlist do not get updated. I even printed out the apollo store/cache and I see the values getting updated. why is the flatlist not re-rendering after the cache write?

```
   render() {


 const { posts, isFetching, lastUpdated, location, navigation, data, likeMutation, username, distancePointLatitude, distancePointLongitude, searchPointLatitude, searchPointLongitude } = this.props


 <FlatList
  data={data.near}
  style={styles.scrollViewContent}
  extraData={this.props.store}
  //renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => item.posts.length != 0 && <ListItem>

{item.posts[0].userInteraction.userLike ? <Icon name='md-heart' style={{ color: 'crimson',fontSize: 28}} /> 
          : <Icon name='heart' style={{ fontSize: 26}} 

          onPress={() => likeMutation({ variables: { elementId: item.posts[0].postId, userId: username  },

            update: (store, { data: { addLike } }) => {
              // Read the data from our cache for this query.

              var thisLocationRadius = {searchPointLongitude: searchPointLongitude,
                searchPointLatitude: searchPointLatitude,
                radius: fiftyMilesInMeters, distancePointLongitude: distancePointLongitude,
                 distancePointLatitude: distancePointLatitude };


              var data = store.readQuery({ query: getLocalPosts,
                variables: {
                locationRadius: thisLocationRadius,
                userId: username
              }, });


             data.near[index].posts[0].userInteraction.userLike = true

              data.near[index].posts[0].interactionStats.totalLikes + 1


              // Write our data back to the cache.
              store.writeQuery({ query: getLocalPosts, data });



            },
          }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('there was an error sending the query', error);
          })} />  }
}

  const HomeWithData = graphql(getLocalPosts, {
        options:  ({ searchPointLongitude, searchPointLatitude, distancePointLongitude, distancePointLatitude, username }) => ({ variables: { locationRadius: {searchPointLongitude: searchPointLongitude,
           searchPointLatitude: searchPointLatitude,
           radius: fiftyMilesInMeters, distancePointLongitude: distancePointLongitude,
            distancePointLatitude: distancePointLatitude }, userId: username } }),

        });


export default compose( connect(mapStateToProps),
HomeWithData,
graphql(like, { name: 'likeMutation' }))(Home);
```

getLocalPosts Query:

```
export const getLocalPosts = gql`query getLocalPosts($locationRadius: locationRadius!, , $userId: String!) {
    near(locationRadius: $locationRadius){
      name,
      address,
      phonenumber,
      email,
      website,
      about,
      location {
        longitude,
        latitude
      },
      distance(unit: MILE),
      businessId,
      hours {
        weekDay,
        startTime,
        endTime
      },
      posts(isActive: true) {
        postText,
        postId,
        userInteraction(userId: $userId){
          userLike
        },
        interactionStats{
          totalLikes
        }
      },
    }
    }`;
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you defined your query operation and connected it to the flat list?

Comment: @TalZ I have added the code you requested that contains my query operation and how it is connected to flat list.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that Apollo takes into account a few things when it decides which query listener should be triggered after a change, including the `variables` field.

In your case, your component with the flat list is not re-rendered because the query isn't notified of a change. It isn't notified of a change because Apollo thinks it is a different query than the one you are updating in the store when you call `writeQuery`.

So the solution is to add the `variables` field when you call `writeQuery`. And it should have the same values you use when the query is called.

Assuming these have the correct values, your call to `store.writeQuery` should look something like this:

```
          store.writeQuery({ 
            query: getLocalPosts, 
            data, 
            variables: {
              locationRadius: thisLocationRadius,
              userId: username
            }
          });
```

Comment: That's very interesting. I've spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot this with no likely explanation. It wouldn't have occurred to me specify the variables again, particularly when I already noted them in "readQuery" in my case. Oh well, live and learn. Upvoted!

Comment: THANKS and happy new year (from Asia)

Comment: Thanks, this worked but I literally have no idea why it should

Comment: busted my day because of missing variables param 